# How to use a method inside v-if

Tags: asp.net, vue.js, jwt, vuejs3

I'm trying to display countries from database which the continentId foreach country == logged user scope.
An user scope is between 1-5.
here is my vue template

```
 <div class="container w-75" v-show="showGrid">   
    <div class="row" style="width:900px; height:900px; padding-left:200px">
        <div class="col-md-4" v-for="country of countries" v-bind:key="country">                
 <div v-if="country.continentId==setup" class="card p-3" style="cursor:pointer">
                <router-link :to="{ path: '/FetchData', query: { query: country.countryName}}">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-row mb-3">

                        <div class="d-flex flex-column ml-2"><span>{{country.countryId}}</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <h6 style="text-align:left">{{country.countryName}}</h6>
                </router-link>                    
            </div>
```

and those are my methods

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    async getCountries() {
      let country = this.$route.query.query
      if (!country) {
        await axios
          .get("https://localhost:44391/api/Pho/GetCountries")
          .then((res) => (this.countries = res.data))
      } else {
        await axios
          .get(
            "https://localhost:44391/api/Pho/GetCountries?country=" +
              this.$route.query.query
          )
          .then((res) => (this.countries = res.data))
        this.searchbar = false
      }
    },

    async setup() {
      let token = "??"
      const scope = ref("")
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://localhost:44391/api/Auth/UserScope",
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
          },
          credentials: "include",
        }
      )
      const content = response.json()
      scope.value = `${content.scope}`
      return {
        scope,
      }
    },
  },
  async mounted() {
    this.setup()
    await this.getCountries()
  },
}
```

the method setup return le scope of the logged user and the getCountries method returns the list of countries.

when i inspect i find that the scope is returned but the  `<div v-if="country.continentId==setup" class="card p-3" style="cursor:pointer">` condition does not work properly.

Comment: can you please show what data `countries` contain.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal here is an example     {
    "countryId": "AE",
    "countryName": "United Arab Emirates",
    "continentId": 7
  },

Comment: As per your code, you have this check `v-if="country.continentId==setup"` but `contentId` is containing a numeric value and you are comparing it with `string`. That's the reason it is not working or do you have any mapping object for `continentId` ?

Comment: @RohìtJíndal no i thought that it would apply the comparison by using v-if country.continentId==setup

Comment: but how it will work ? As in your object, continentId is containing numeric value and in template you are comparing it with a string value.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal  i did the parseInt  for the value scope but it didnt work either

Comment: It's not about type casting. It's all about the property value & type mismatch with the value you are comparing in the `v-if`.

Comment: what should i do

Comment: It should be `country.continentId=== 7` or any other integer based on the condition you want to put.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal i need to test the returned value of the method setup

Comment: Yes that's what i asked for initially and you shared with me `{ "countryId": "AE", "countryName": "United Arab Emirates", "continentId": 7 }`. Hence, based on this data I give my opinion to you.

Answer (score 2):

The `setup()` hook is not supposed to be under `methods`. It needs to be at the top level of the object:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    // setup() { /*...*/ } ❌
  },
  setup() { /*...*/ }, ✅
}
```

Also, don't make the `setup()` hook `async` unless you're intentionally making it an *async component*, which requires a `<Suspense>` as an ancestor. Instead, move the asynchronous code into its own function within:

```js
export default {
  setup() {
    const scope = ref('')

    const fetchUserScope = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(/*...*/)
      const content = await response.json()
      scope.value = content.scope
    }
    fetchUserScope()

    return { scope }
  }
}
```

Also, you can't invoke the `setup()` hook from the template like that. You're really just trying to compare `continentId` to the `scope` value, so use `scope` directly:

```html
<!-- <div v-if="country.continentId == setup"> --> ❌
<div v-if="country.continentId == scope"> ✅
```

You shouldn't try to invoke `setup()` from `mounted()` hook either. Vue controls the lifecycle hooks itself:

```js
export default {
  mounted() {
    // this.setup() ❌
  }
}
```

Comment: I suppose that the method was incidentally called setup, and there's no connection to composition api

Comment: yes but by doing the countries lists doesn't appear

Comment: @EstusFlask Yes, definitely possible, but the fact that it's named `setup()` and it's returning a `ref`, just like one would do in the `setup()` hook, I'm assuming the OP was actually trying to use the hook.

Comment: @NesrineMissaoui I need more context to determine the problem. Can you share a link to a reproduction? e.g., in StackBlitz